# Не обрабатывается исключение в C++

Tags: c++, visual-c++, исключения, обработка-ошибок

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;
//int error(string text) {
//  cout << text << '\n';
//  return 0;
//}
int main() {
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Russian");
    try {
        vector <int> v;
        for (int x; cin >> x;) {
            v.push_back(x);
        }
        for (int i = 0; i <= v.size(); ++i) {
            cout << "v[" << i << "] = " << v[i] << '\n';
        }
    } catch (out_of_range) { // Этот обработчик почему то не работает
        cerr << "Ошибка диапазона!\n";
        return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

> Делал всё как в книге по С++ от Страуструпа, но по какой то причине
> это код выдаёт ошибку а не обрабатывает исключение. Помогите пж как
> сделать что бы исключение out_of_range обрабатывалось?

Comment: Доступ по несуществующему индексу вектора при помощи `operator[]` вызывает неопределённое поведение. Эквивалент `operator[]`, генерирующий исключение `std::out_of_range` для некорректного индекса — это функция-член [at()](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/at).

Answer (score 1):

И снова должен отправить вас к ответу https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1368181/195342 на ваш подобный вопрос.

Я вам писал — *Вот этот заголовочный файл вы должны скачать и включать во все программы из книги Страуструпа...*

Не понимаю, вы сознательно это не делаете?

В этом заголовочном файле определен новый класс `Vector`, который генерирует исключения (в отличие от `vector`), а потом  определено

```
#define vector Vector
```

Еще раз и очень медленно, как для милиционера: в этой книге Страуструпа вы обязаны во все программы включать файл

```
#include "std_lib_facilities.h"
```

Понимаете? **ВО ВСЕ**. Почему вы это не делаете?

И, кстати, только его. А не вот эти ваши

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <cmath>
```

Или вы не смотрели мой ответ вообще? Он поэтому не помечен как принятый? Вы только задаете вопросы, но не читаете ответы?

P.S. У меня подозрение, что и книгу Страуструпа вы не читаете, а так, выхватываете какие-то куски кода...

Comment: Страуструп тоже молодец, конечно. Переопределил стандартные контейнеры... Лучше бы рассказал, как в популярных компиляторах включить дебажные проверки на выход за границы контейнеров.

Comment: Он стандарт поправляет, что бы пофиксить баги в книгах, а Вы о компиляторах...